How to configure flutter_launcher_icons for adaptive icons?
I'm having trouble configuring flutter_launcher_icons for my app. When I use the .yaml below with my opaque png, it looks great:
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.13.1"

flutter_launcher_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  image_path_ios: "assets/icon/app_icon_ios.png"
  image_path_android: "assets/icon/app_icon_android.png"
  min_sdk_android: 21 # android min sdk min:16, default 21


But when I remove the purple background and make it translucent and use a background image, I get this? How do I keep the look of my opaque png when configuring an adaptive icon?
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.13.1"

flutter_launcher_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path_ios: "assets/icon/app_icon_ios.png"
  image_path_android: "assets/icon/app_icon_android.png"
  adaptive_icon_background: "assets/icon/app_icon_background.png"
  adaptive_icon_foreground: "assets/icon/app_icon_android.png"


